# how to import anular typescript component as string

Tags: angular, webpack

the goal is to load the content of the component as string inside of the same component
for some reason angular gets to this file before webpack the dependency injector fills the file with garbage.

anyone got suggestions on how to approach this situation ?

thanks

PS: the html and scss files present weird artefacts in development mode only.

```
import tsContent from './checkbox-page.component.ts?raw';
```

typings.d.ts

```
declare module '*?raw' {
  const rawFileContent: string
  export default rawFileContent
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        resourceQuery: /raw/,
        type: 'asset/source'
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

output

```
tsContent // import cssContent from './-checkbox-page.component.scss';
import tsContent from './-checkbox-page.component.ts?raw';
import htmlContent from './-checkbox-page.component.html?raw';
import scssContent from './-checkbox-page.component.scss?raw';
import * as i0 from "@angular/core"; // import htmlContent from './a.txt';

console.log('tsContent', tsContent);
export let CheckboxPageComponent = /*#__PURE__*/(() => {
  class CheckboxPageComponent {
    constructor() {
      this.typescript = tsContent;
      this.styles = scssContent;
      this.html = htmlContent;
    }

  }

  CheckboxPageComponent.ɵfac = function CheckboxPageComponent_Factory(t) {
    return new (t || CheckboxPageComponent)();
  };

  CheckboxPageComponent.ɵcmp = /*@__PURE__*/i0.ɵɵdefineComponent({
    type: CheckboxPageComponent,
    selectors: [["checkbox-page"]],
    decls: 20,
    vars: 3,
    template: function CheckboxPageComponent_Template(rf, ctx) {
      if (rf & 1) {
        i0.ɵɵelement(0, "br");
        i0.ɵɵelement(1, "br");
        i0.ɵɵelementStart(2, "h1");
        i0.ɵɵtext(3, "HTML");
        i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
        i0.ɵɵelementStart(4, "pre");
        i0.ɵɵtext(5);
        i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
        i0.ɵɵelement(6, "hr");
        i0.ɵɵelement(7, "br");
        i0.ɵɵelement(8, "br");
        i0.ɵɵelementStart(9, "h1");
```

Comment: Do you want to present the compiled file, or do you want to have a string representation of the component.ts file?

Comment: I need the original content of the file